# How to hide all labels from modelformset_factory generated inputs?

Tags: python, django

I have following code in forms.py

```
class MCQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.MultipleChoiceQuestion
        fields = ('prompt',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MCQuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        self.fields['choice'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=self.instance.choice.all(),
                                                   widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                                   empty_label=None)


MCQuestionFormSetForUser = modelformset_factory(models.MultipleChoiceQuestion,
                                            fields=('prompt',),
                                            form=MCQuestionForm,
                                            extra=0,
                                            widgets={
                                                'prompt': forms.TextInput(
                                                    attrs={'readonly': True, 'class': 'borderless'})
                                            }
                                            )
```

When I place "MCQuestionFormSetForUser" as formset.as_p in a template both prompt field and choices get corresponding labels. How can I hide them?

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do that

```
class MCQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.MultipleChoiceQuestion
        fields = ('prompt',)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MCQuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['choice'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=self.instance.choice.all(),
                                                   widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                                   empty_label=None)

            # here is the override that I was looking for
            self.fields['choice'].label = ''
            self.fields['prompt'].label = ''
```